# C# - Access values from another private void on same form

Tags: c#

Is it possible to access **`private string`** from another **`private void`** on same form not another form?

```
private void english()
{
    string value1 = "Hello!";
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = value1;
}
```

The error is: **The name 'value1' does not exist in the current context**

Comment: Have you read any book? Because, you are the first person I have ever seen who are talkin ggabout methods as`private something`. These are `methods`.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev - What is wrong if I try to ask and try understand?! this comment make users be shy to ask again!

Comment: Nothing wrong of course. But, these are very fundamental elements of programming. It would be better to learn a bit about them before trying to write something.

Comment: @rami-yrm  Asking something you don't know is your right , but we could ask the user to do some homework also .So others would be able to understand your question easily and reply .

Comment: @rami-yrm StackOverflow requires that the questioner demonstrates basic knowledge of the question he is asking as part of the rules.

Comment: I tried before ask this question. I need more to understand c# I know that, but something you just know you didn't understand it correctly! you have to ask and try get it by another ways. Anyway thanks for reply to know its from very fundamental element of programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access a local variable which is inside another method. Local variables are variables that are declared in scope of a method (in your case - in method `english()`. These variables can only be accessed from the same method.

However, what you can do is to create a class field outside of method `english()`, in this case it will be accessible from any non static method on this class:

```
private string value1;
private void english()
{
    value1 = "Hello!";
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = value1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the previous answer. Scopes defines where your variables are available.
Scopes can be seen as a "fancy name" for the brackets if your very new to c#.

```
class Program
{
    private string _sPrivate; //This is a private variable, only accessable to methods within the class.
    public string PublicString; //This is a public variable, it is accessable outside the class.

    private void _privateMethod(string this_is_an_argument) //This is a method, since it is private, it is only available inside the above class.
    {
        string thisIsAvar; //this has been defined inside _privateMethod, and is ONLY available inside _privateMethod.
    }
    public void PublicMethod() //This is a public method. It can be called outside the class, on the class itself. Code running in here can still access the private variables inside the class.
    {
        _sPrivate = "I just changed the private var"; //This will work.
        thisIsAvar = "This is impossible, because thisIsAvar doesn't exist here"; //This will throw an error. Since thisIsAvar isn't defined inside this scope.
    }
}
```